# c# using ActiveDir to get names under a managers org chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

i am using ODBC to pull data from active directory to get the email for a particular username using the code below.

how can i use AD to pull all the usernames of peolel who report into a prticular manager?

i can transverse the org chart in outlook so im thinking i can do the same using AD...

ideas?

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd;

        con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=ADsDSOObject;dsn=Active Directory Provider");
        con.Open();

        //Create a command object on this connection
        string strSQL = "SELECT mail FROM 'LDAP://DC=amrs,DC=win,DC=ml,dc=COM' WHERE samaccountname = '" + UserName.Replace(@"AMRS\", "") + "'";
        cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQL, con);

        try
        {
            return Convert.ToString (  cmd.ExecuteScalar() );
        }
        catch (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException exc)
        {
            return "ERROR: " + exc.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the manager attribute in AD is set? It should return you the distinguished name of the manager.  You can then parse the string to figure out the samAccountName of the manager.
Then just repeat your search using the manager's distinguished name.

Now if the manager attribute isn't set....

Maybe search by department code, and then check the title of everyone in the department?

Might want to look into the [Directory Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t2667d1%28vs.71%29.aspx) class.

This [link](http://www.willasrari.com/blog/query-active-directory-users-using-c/000133.aspx) gives you a basic tutorial on how to query AD

Comment: is the way i pull data from Ad in my code sample usable for something like this? i think there are other ways in .net to connect to AD that may be better???

Comment: Yes, OldDb way would probably work.  You probably need to do select manager from  .... (and then recursively go through the chain).  I updated my answer to add some information about Directory Services

Comment: when i run SELECT top 50
 manager 
    FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, '
    SELECT manager
    FROM ''LDAP://DC=amrs,DC=win,DC=ml,dc=COM''
    WHERE objectClass=''user'' AND objectClass<>''computer''
    ') AS tblADSI
where manager is not null
i get "CN=Parlapiano\, Jim,OU=Users,OU=Technology,OU=IDS,DC=amrs,DC=win,DC=ml,DC=com" not just manager username. whats up with that?

Comment: that's the individual's distinguishedname (or canano.  it's kind of like their foreign key.  You can either parse the string to get the samAccountName (Parlapiano) or use that string in a where clause - so where distinguishedname = "Cn=Parlapiano,Ou=..."